# Linking HTML Table with sql database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am new to html tables in vb.net.

i have an html table with all functionality i need (Expanding and collapsing row on click etc) ,how can i link that table with sql database.

I can show database details in grid view..

But My table have functions such as on click of row ,the row having 4 fields must expand down with  10 text boxes (other than shown on row) must be displayed together with few buttons.Hence i used javascript for expand/collapse row

As told how can i make the rendered grid view row clickable and expandable

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use an asp.net control called a GridView. When rendered, it becomes an HTML table. It can then be manipulated by CSS and Javascript.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx

GridView not being an option, try using a Literal:

```
<asp:Literal ID="LiteralTable" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Codebehind:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("<table>");
for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
{
    sb.Append("<tr class=\"clickable\"><td>" + FirstColumn[i] + "</td>" + "<td>" + SecondColumn[i] + "</td></tr>");
    sb.Append("<tr class=\"expandable\"><td>Edit</td>" + "<td>More Info</td></tr>");
}

sb.Append("</table>");


LiteralTable.Text = sb.ToString();
```

And then work your javascript (or jquery) magic:

```
$(".clickable").click().next().show();
```

And in this case just load your database into the array before calling the stringbuilder!

Comment: I think i can not use grid view for this purpose,because on row click i need that row to expand down with edit and disable button together with textboxes etc.

Comment: How are you currently managing the expand-on-click function? I would assume javascript. Could you include some code in your post? Table and script preferred.

Comment: <table width="772px" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" frame="box">  
        <tr style="cursor: pointer;" bgcolor="#4682B4" onclick="toggle_visibility('tbl1'); this.style.backgroundColor='green';"></style>   
            <td class="style9" </td> 
                <font size="4" face="tahoma" color="white"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; LicenseID</strong></font><td 
                class="style8" </td>

Comment: Grid view When rendered, it becomes an HTML table.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET WebForms, it's actually really easy to make GridView to suit your needs.

You can either use Visual Studio's built-in toolkit, and just drag to your WebForm, set your SQLDataSource, and set to selectable, and then to editable.  I think VS 2010 and up have a quick code generated one by using toolkit, but here's what the code might look like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPreview" runat="server" CssClass="gvPreview" AutoGenerateEditButton="true"> 
        </asp:GridView>
```

I don't have SQL on my machine at the moment so I can't use the GUI Wizard exactly to show you what it would look like, but I can.